# UTF-8 not working outside the header

Tags: php, utf-8, header, include

Utf-8 works just for text generated in header, but not for text in (for example) index. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

header.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
....
```

for example: index.php

```
<?php
include "header.php";
?>
...body stuff
```

Thanks :)

Comment: HTML5 uses `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your file encoding. I don't know what editor you usually use, but in Eclipse you can have a look to in via right click on a file -> properties

For database, check the encoding of each fields & be sure to call "set names utf8" query each time you open a mysql connexion

Comment: Yes i use PHP designer. And i have set it to utf-8. But the problem is that it doesnt work outside the header (in file where header is included).

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? If you replace "body stuff" in your example by, say "éèàç" what happens? I just want to be sure that it's not related to some content  you fetch from a database

Comment: It is mix of both. Normal html text AND <select> options i fetch from mysql database. (Database is utf-8.)

Comment: For the DB you have to be sure that you call the query "set names utf8;" for each sql connexion you do. For the static HTML, you can play with iconv if PHPEditor doesn't allow you to do some conversions

Comment: Hmm okay, i didnt use "set names". Ill try that :) Tnanks